# I don't knw why my output goes to my last number when it's supposed to go to the number indicated by Target Integer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
#pragma once

namespace PointerArray {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox9;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox10;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox11;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox12;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox13;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox14;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox15;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox16;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label10;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnData;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnSort;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnSearch;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label11;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtTarget;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox13 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox14 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox15 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox16 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->btnData = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->btnSort = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->btnSearch = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtTarget = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 55);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 91);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label2->Text = L"label2";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 123);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label3->Text = L"label3";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 155);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label4->Text = L"label4";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 188);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label5->Text = L"label5";
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->AutoSize = true;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 221);
            this->label6->Name = L"label6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label6->Text = L"label6";
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this->label7->AutoSize = true;
            this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 254);
            this->label7->Name = L"label7";
            this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label7->TabIndex = 6;
            this->label7->Text = L"label7";
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this->label8->AutoSize = true;
            this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(335, 290);
            this->label8->Name = L"label8";
            this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label8->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label8->Text = L"label8";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 52);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 88);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 120);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 155);
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // textBox5
            // 
            this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 185);
            this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
            this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox5->TabIndex = 12;
            // 
            // textBox6
            // 
            this->textBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 218);
            this->textBox6->Name = L"textBox6";
            this->textBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox6->TabIndex = 13;
            // 
            // textBox7
            // 
            this->textBox7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 251);
            this->textBox7->Name = L"textBox7";
            this->textBox7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox7->TabIndex = 14;
            // 
            // textBox8
            // 
            this->textBox8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(229, 283);
            this->textBox8->Name = L"textBox8";
            this->textBox8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox8->TabIndex = 15;
            // 
            // textBox9
            // 
            this->textBox9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 52);
            this->textBox9->Name = L"textBox9";
            this->textBox9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox9->TabIndex = 23;
            // 
            // textBox10
            // 
            this->textBox10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 85);
            this->textBox10->Name = L"textBox10";
            this->textBox10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox10->TabIndex = 22;
            // 
            // textBox11
            // 
            this->textBox11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 120);
            this->textBox11->Name = L"textBox11";
            this->textBox11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox11->TabIndex = 21;
            // 
            // textBox12
            // 
            this->textBox12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 155);
            this->textBox12->Name = L"textBox12";
            this->textBox12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox12->TabIndex = 20;
            // 
            // textBox13
            // 
            this->textBox13->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 185);
            this->textBox13->Name = L"textBox13";
            this->textBox13->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox13->TabIndex = 19;
            // 
            // textBox14
            // 
            this->textBox14->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 218);
            this->textBox14->Name = L"textBox14";
            this->textBox14->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox14->TabIndex = 18;
            // 
            // textBox15
            // 
            this->textBox15->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 251);
            this->textBox15->Name = L"textBox15";
            this->textBox15->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox15->TabIndex = 17;
            // 
            // textBox16
            // 
            this->textBox16->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 283);
            this->textBox16->Name = L"textBox16";
            this->textBox16->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox16->TabIndex = 16;
            // 
            // label9
            // 
            this->label9->AutoSize = true;
            this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(52, 24);
            this->label9->Name = L"label9";
            this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(67, 13);
            this->label9->TabIndex = 24;
            this->label9->Text = L"Pointer Array";
            // 
            // label10
            // 
            this->label10->AutoSize = true;
            this->label10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(247, 24);
            this->label10->Name = L"label10";
            this->label10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(57, 13);
            this->label10->TabIndex = 25;
            this->label10->Text = L"Data Array";
            // 
            // btnData
            // 
            this->btnData->Location = System::Drawing::Point(31, 391);
            this->btnData->Name = L"btnData";
            this->btnData->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->btnData->TabIndex = 26;
            this->btnData->Text = L"Data";
            this->btnData->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnData->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnData_Click);
            // 
            // btnSort
            // 
            this->btnSort->Location = System::Drawing::Point(146, 391);
            this->btnSort->Name = L"btnSort";
            this->btnSort->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->btnSort->TabIndex = 27;
            this->btnSort->Text = L"Sort";
            this->btnSort->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnSort->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnSort_Click);
            // 
            // btnSearch
            // 
            this->btnSearch->Location = System::Drawing::Point(255, 391);
            this->btnSearch->Name = L"btnSearch";
            this->btnSearch->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->btnSearch->TabIndex = 28;
            this->btnSearch->Text = L"Search";
            this->btnSearch->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnSearch->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnSearch_Click);
            // 
            // label11
            // 
            this->label11->AutoSize = true;
            this->label11->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(27, 334);
            this->label11->Name = L"label11";
            this->label11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(110, 20);
            this->label11->TabIndex = 29;
            this->label11->Text = L"Target Integer";
            // 
            // txtTarget
            // 
            this->txtTarget->Location = System::Drawing::Point(143, 336);
            this->txtTarget->Name = L"txtTarget";
            this->txtTarget->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txtTarget->TabIndex = 30;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(467, 641);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtTarget);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label11);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnSearch);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnSort);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnData);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label10);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label9);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox9);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox10);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox11);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox12);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox13);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox14);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox15);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox16);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Pointer Array Program";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        int* arr;
        int** ptr;
        Graphics^ g;
        Pen^ blackPen; 
        private: String^ strTarget;


private: void swap(int** a, int** b)
{
    int* temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}


private: void displayPtr()
{
    // Display ptr values in textBox9 - textBox16
    textBox9->Text = ((int) ptr[0]).ToString();
    textBox10->Text = ((int) ptr[1]).ToString();
    textBox11->Text = ((int) ptr[2]).ToString();
    textBox12->Text = ((int) ptr[3]).ToString();
    textBox13->Text = ((int) ptr[4]).ToString();
    textBox14->Text = ((int) ptr[5]).ToString();
    textBox15->Text = ((int) ptr[6]).ToString();
    textBox16->Text = ((int) ptr[7]).ToString();

    // Assigns textBox values to corresponding labels
    label1->Text = ((int) ptr[0]).ToString();
    label2->Text = ((int) ptr[1]).ToString();
    label3->Text = ((int) ptr[2]).ToString();
    label4->Text = ((int) ptr[3]).ToString();
    label5->Text = ((int) ptr[4]).ToString();
    label6->Text = ((int) ptr[5]).ToString();
    label7->Text = ((int) ptr[6]).ToString();
    label8->Text = ((int) ptr[7]).ToString();
}


private: void drawLines()
{
    // Calculate start points (ptrX, ptrY)
    int ptrX = textBox9->Location.X + textBox9->Width;
    int ptrY = textBox9->Location.Y + textBox9->Height/2;

    // Calculate end point (arrX)
    int arrX = textBox1->Location.X;
    int arrY;
    int startY = textBox1->Location.Y + textBox1->Height/2;
    // Refresh the form and draw lines 
    this->Refresh();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        arrY = startY + ((ptr[i] - &(arr[0])) * 32);
        g->DrawLine(blackPen, ptrX, ptrY, arrX, arrY);
        ptrY += 32;
    }
}

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             arr = new int[8];
             ptr = new int*[8];
             g = this->CreateGraphics();
             blackPen = gcnew System::Drawing::Pen(Color::Black);
             btnSort->Enabled = false;
             }

private: System::Void btnData_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             // Declare Variables and Create Random Number Generator
             int i; // Loop Control Variable
             Random^ randomNumber;
             DateTime now = DateTime::Now;
             randomNumber = gcnew Random(now.Millisecond);

             // Assign random numbers to arr
             for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
                 arr[i] = randomNumber->Next(0, 100);

             // Display arr values in textBox1 - textBox8
             textBox1->Text = arr[0].ToString();
             textBox2->Text = arr[1].ToString();
             textBox3->Text = arr[2].ToString();
             textBox4->Text = arr[3].ToString();
             textBox5->Text = arr[4].ToString();
             textBox6->Text = arr[5].ToString();
             textBox7->Text = arr[6].ToString();
             textBox8->Text = arr[7].ToString();

             // Assign element addresses to ptr
             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) ptr[i] = &arr[i];


             // Display the pointer array values
             displayPtr();

             // Draw lines connecting the pointer and data arrays
             drawLines();

             // Turn on Sort Button
             btnSort->Enabled = true;
         }
private: System::Void btnSort_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             // Declare Variables
             String^ output = "";
             int i, j;
             int arrTotal;
             // Bubble sort the ptr array
             for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                 for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                     if (*ptr[j] > *ptr[j+1])
                         swap(&(ptr[j]), &(ptr[j+1]));

             // Display pointers with their new address contents
             displayPtr();
             // Concatenate values in sorted order onto output String
             for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) output += (*ptr[i]).ToString() + "\r\n";
             // Draw lines connecting pointer array and data array
             drawLines();
             // Display sorted data in MessageBox

             arrTotal = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4] + arr[5] + arr[6] + arr[7];
             MessageBox::Show(output, "Sorted Data");
             MessageBox::Show("Sorted Data Sum = " + arrTotal.ToString());

             // Draw lines again after MessageBox is closed
             drawLines();
         }

private: System::Void btnSearch_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             // Declare and Initalize Variables
             String^ output = "";
             int i; 
             bool found = false;
             // Read the Target
```

Error here -------------------------------------------------------------

I have no idea why my for loop jumps to the end when it's supposed to go to the number that the user inputs into my txtTarget textBox (says "Enter Integer") I'm not sure how to fix this problem and as far as I can tell my loop makes sense but I'm not sure any and all help is appreciated

```
             for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) output = (*ptr[i]).ToString(); + "\r\n";
             MessageBox::Show(output->ToString());
             MessageBox::Show(output, "Target Found "); 
         }
};
}
```

Comment: Concise code example would really help us.  There is a lot of fluff.  This also appears to be C++11 code yes?  I would tag it as such.  Finally, do you have an aversion to using braces {} on loops?  I'm willing to be you will get bit before long by this.

Comment: Debug and follow it, then "as far as I can tell" will be much further.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance `ptr[i]` contains bad pointers at this point - Not NULL as that would crash, but hanging pointers that are clobbering your stack based counter `i`?  That's my guess.  In addition:

Your swap function scares me a bit in its use of double pointers.  `std::swap` would be better.

This:

```
        // Bubble sort the ptr array
         for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
             for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                 if (*ptr[j] > *ptr[j+1])
                     swap(&(ptr[j]), &(ptr[j+1]));
```

Is a very poor sort and probably wrong as it does double the work it should as written.   Can you use `std::sort()` here?

```
        // Display sorted data in MessageBox

         arrTotal = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4] + arr[5] + arr[6] + arr[7];
```

Use a for loop or algorithm call instead to help you if you ever add another value to your array.

next, this:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         arr = new int[8];
         ptr = new int*[8];
```

Those 8s are magic numbers and asking for future trouble.  Using RAII to handle your allocations would be cleaner and safer.

Finally for now:

```
textBox9->Text = ((int) ptr[0]).ToString();
```

is not 64-bit safe and should be throwing warnings.

Have you set your compiler warnings to a high level and fixed them all?  As they will probably show you other things wrong that I haven't even seen yet.